# send a html link in a email sent by php

Tags: php, html, email

I am using html form textarea and php to send email using my website

How can i put a link in the message body. i did like this

```
<a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/">Visit the site</a>
```

but i am receiving whole text. also i tried

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/">Visit the site</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

but i am receiving whole text

Comment: Let us know what code are you writing for sending email

Comment: and where is the code to send email ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you add headers correctly

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

SEE [Example #4 Sending HTML email](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to set the content-type declaration within the message header sent to the mail server?

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

set headers to `text/html`

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1";
```

see the example : [PHP mail() function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is certainly in your header

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

with these headers, your content will be correctly interpreted.

Take a look [here](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)